# Command button to paste table based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet in which I'm trying to make a walkthrough type of thing, for training new employees. At its core, I want to have a dropdown menu (got that already) filled with options, and then a command button that will check the contents of the drop down cell, and copy-paste a table from a hidden sheet onto the main sheet. For some reason, I can't get the button to work. This is what I've got so far:

```
Private Sub button_desk_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Create Table
If Worksheets("Walkthrough").Range("A2").Value2 = "Getting your desk set up" Then
    Sheets("Settings").Select
    Range("lookup_desksetup[[#All],[Getting your desk setup]]").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Walkthrough").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've tried a few different approaches for this, including not using the `.Select` command, but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: That's actually where it is in the code - let me fix the post.

Comment: The dreaded "doesn't work" - what exactly is the problem? You should certainly remove all those Selects.

Comment: To add to above you cannot select a sheet which is hidden. You could unhide it and then paste but can avoid all that by eliminating the Selects.

Comment: The sheet isn't hidden yet, that's the plan for later. I originally had code written with no Select command, but it wasn't working either so I changed it up. By "doesn't work" I mean literally you click the command button and nothing happens.

Comment: Have you checked the If condition is satisfied?

Comment: It should be - I changed the dropdown column to the matching value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets("Settings").Select
Range("lookup_desksetup[[#All],[Getting your desk setup]]").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Walkthrough").Select
Range("B5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

is a long winded way of saying

```
Sheets("Settings").Range("lookup_desksetup[[#All],[Getting your desk setup]]").copy _
               destination:= Sheets("Walkthrough").Range("B5")
```

However I suspect that your problem is that "lookup_desksetup[[#All],[Getting your desk setup]]" is a very funny range name and may not actually exist as a valid name in that sheet?

Comment: "lookup_desksetup[[#All],[Getting your desk setup]]" is a table in one of my sheets. I pulled that range directly from the code for a macro (I recorded a macro doing pretty much exactly what I wanted and just copy pasted the range).

I tried the shorter version of code in your response - I'll give it another shot, maybe my syntax was wrong or something.

Comment: So "Getting your desk setup" is one of the column names?

Comment: Correct. The only column name in fact.